# Phosphoryl bromide reaction with benzoic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I am trying to find out how $\ce{POBr3}$ reacts with $\ce{-COOH}$ group (benzoic acid to be specific). I found that it performs an elimination reaction with alcohols to give alkenes. I have also seen that keto group was converted to $\ce{-Cl}$ using $\ce{POCl3}.$

But I don't think that $\ce{POCl3}$ will eliminate $\ce{-COOH}$ group — that seems like nonsense. Eliminating using $\ce{-OH}$ from $\ce{-COOH}$ would give me a carbon with five bonds. Exchanging the $\ce{=O}$ from $\ce{-COOH}$ would give me something I have never seen and it doesn't even look good…

So I am sort of out of ideas. I'd appreciate any hint what to do.

Comment: I've not see this done this way but my gut feeling is that you would get the acyl bromide. Anyone got any references or other thoughts?

Comment: I don't know about POBr3 but PBr3 has been used to brominate carboxylic acid to produce alpha-bromocarboxylic acid. This is the base for HVZ reaction. I cannot say if this happens for benzoic acid since it can be brominated using Br2/FeBr3.

Comment: SciFinder does not uncover any published reactions that use a carboxylic acid and $\ce{POBr3}$ or $\ce{POCl3}$. Thus, it seems we will have to speculate about the answer.

Comment: @Waylander you are correct :) thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Well actually @Waylander and @Nilay Ghosh are both correct in a way. To convert carboxylic acids into acyl chloride, $\ce{PCl5}$ is often used as a chlorinating agent , which yields an acyl chloride and $\ce{POCl3}$ (and $\ce{HCl}$) as a by-product.

This $\ce{POBr3}$ (or likewise $\ce{POCl3}$) is essentially a dehydrating agent and is thus used to dehydrate alcohols to alkenes[(1)](http://cook.chem.ndsu.nodak.edu/chem342/chem342_09/files/lecture15.pdf)

[image: POBr3 promoted dehydration via E2 elimination]

or brominate[(2)](https://reagents.acsgcipr.org/reagent-guides/bromination/list-of-reagents/deoxy-bromination) (in some cases) to form alkyl bromides.
[image: Deoxy bromination using POBr3]

But this dehydrating capability might also be used on carboxylic acids to convert them into their anhydrides just like $\ce{P4O10}$, though there's no such special mention of the viability of the reaction progress.

But since you're really asking, I think conversion of the acid into its anhydride could be a possible outcome in presence of a dehydrating agent $\ce{POBr3}$.

Answer (score 1):

So the correct answer (according to my teacher) is that R-COBr is generated from the reaction of POBr3 with R-COOH (benzoic acid)